# Update database instance with specific form fields using Django (modify_personal_info)

Tags: django, forms, django-views, django-templates

I am quite new to Django, and I am working on a project, and I am trying to create a page to modify user data (code down below). What I am trying to do is allow the user to change one or more field, and not necessarily all the fields at the same time, and then update the user instance, I tried using multiple conditions on each field so I won't have an empty field in the database later, but nothing happens.
Here's the corresponding view:

```
@login_required
def profile(request, id_user):
    try:
        user = Account.objects.get(pk=id_user)
        if request.method == 'POST': 
            form= request.POST
            if form.get('first_name'):
                user = Account(first_name=form.get('first_name'))
                user.save()
            if form.get('last_name'):
                user = Account(last_name=form.get('last_name'))
                user.save()
            if form.get('email'):
                user = Account(email=form.get('email'))
                user.save()
            if form.get('username'):
                user = Account(username=form.get('username'))
                user.save()
            if form.get('adress'):
                user = Account(adress=form.get('adress'))
                user.save()
            if form.get('phone'):
                user = Account(phone=form.get('phone'))
                user.save()
    except Account.DoesNotExist:
        user = None
        raise Http404("User does not exist")

    return render(request, "profile.html")
```

And this is a snippet from the template:

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h6>Informations du compte</h6>
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div >
                    <label for="username">Nom
                        d'utilisateur</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username"
                        class=""
                        placeholder="{{user.username}}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email"
                        class=""
                        placeholder="{{user.email}}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div >
                    <label for="first_name">Prénom</label>
                    <input type="text" id="first-name"
                        class=""
                        placeholder="{{user.first_name}}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div >
                    <label for="last_name">Nom</label>
                    <input type="text" id="last-name"
                        class=""
                        placeholder="{{user.last_name}}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="my-4">
    <h6>Informations de contact</h6>
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div >
                    <label for="adress">Adresse</label>
                    <input id="address" class=""
                        placeholder="{{user.adress}}" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div >
                    <label for="phone">Télephone</label>
                    <input type="text" id="phone"
                        class=""
                        placeholder="{{user.phone}}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card-header bg-white border-0">
<div class="float-sm-right">
    <div>
        <button type="submit" value="appliquer"
            class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Appliquer</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you used these lines to update a Django model object

```
user = Account(first_name=form.get('first_name'))
user.save()
```

but what it actually does is this:
Creates an in-memory object and after calling save that object goes to the database.

it's possible to fix your code but It is too repetitive better way to do your demand is this:

1. In the get request create your form (use Django forms) with an instance:
   `from = AccountFrom(request.POST, instance=user)`
2. Check if the form is valid:
   `if form.is_valid():`
3. and finally save the form:
   `form.save()`

It's also possible to do it yourself in a better way than your code but use django features
You can learn more about django forms from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/django-modelform-create-form-from-models/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. About the first lines I used, they were to select that user instance from the database, I am still reluctant about the django forms, I used them for another function but the styling just wouldn't stick. Anyway, in case I use the django forms and use ` form.save() ` would that save the fields that contain data, or would it overwrite the other fields with empty/null data ?

Comment: They are no longer empty because Django fills them with the data of the selected object and it better in terms of UX because the user can see previous data in the model. Django also handles errors when you call form.is_valid and you can show them to the user.

Comment: Thank you, the link you sent was very simple and instructive whereas the official documentation is a little confusing.